# Understanding the Dart Flutter framework

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Dart too. I need your help in understanding:

1. variables such as `child:`, `body:`, `home:`, etc? Are they `properties` or `labels`? And how are they accessed by the framework?
2. the uses of `:` (colon) in Dart?
3. how best to walk-through the Flutter framework's code?

Thank you.

Comment: `child: `, `body: `, `home: ` are named parameters, not variables. `:` is a separator between key and value in maps and starts the constructor initilizer list. I doubt there is a "best way" to walk through framework code. I don't think this question is a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ouch! But thanks. Yours is **the correct answer**. You read and understood my questions exactly. I looked up the code and found that a call to the function `return` was supplying values to the `named parameters`. Now I get it fine. If you can make this an answer I can mark it as 'Answered.' Just curious, why would you `think this question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow`? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child:` , `body:`, `home:` are named parameters, not variables. `:` is a separator between key and value in map literals and also used to start the constructor initializer list.

I doubt there is a "best way" to walk through framework code